# How to make a row read only on changing a cell value

Tags: jquery, ignite-ui, iggrid

I need to make a row read only based on,changing the cell value of the corresponding row using jQuery.I am using angular IgGrid(Infragistics).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [`editCellEnded`](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.iggridupdating#events:editCellEnded) event of the `igGridUpdating`, and apply `ui-state-disabled` class to the row based on the value of the cell.

```
$(".selector").igGrid({
    features : [
        {
            name : "Updating",
            editCellEnded: function(evt, ui){
                if (ui.value === valueToDisabledOn) {
                    $(".selector").igGrid("rowById", ui.rowID)
                                  .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```